# How to translate gradle jar config in build.gradle into plugin code

Tags: gradle

I earlier asked [this question](http://Jar%20jarTask%20=%20project.getTasks().getByName(%22jar%22);%20jarTask.exclude(%22yang%22);%20jarTask.from(task.yangFilesRootDir);%20jarTask.into(%22META-INF/yang%22);) about configuring the jar task in a particular way.  I now need to translate this into the code in a custom plugin.

The working config in the build.gradle was this:

```
jar {
    exclude "yang"
    from ("src/main/resources/yang") {
        into ("META-INF/yang")
    } 
}
```

This correctly puts classes at the root, but puts the files from "src/main/resources/yang" into "META-INF/yang".

In my custom plugin's "apply" method, I tried doing this in my "project.afterEvaluate()" closure:

```
Jar jarTask = project.getTasks().getByName("jar")
jarTask.exclude("yang")
jarTask.from(task.yangFilesRootDir)
jarTask.into("META-INF/yang")
```

From the API doc for "Jar", I couldn't see any other way to do this that "looks like" what I had in the build script.

This doesn't work.  It does put the files from "src/main/resources/yang" into "META-INF/yang", but it also puts all of the class files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your plugin is implemented in Groovy, you'll want to move the call to `into()` to a configuration closure passed to the `from()` method.

```
jarTask.from(task.yangFilesRootDir) {
    into 'META-INF/yang'
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had figured that out earlier, but I neglected to update this.